# Service workers and the two caches

Tags: javascript, service-worker, browser-cache

I've always assumed (though not seen it explicitly stated) that the following is the path of a HTTPS request when a service worker is installed:

1. The browser encounters an image with a URL. A HTTPS request is initiated.
2. The request passes through the "internal" cache, which will return the resource if it has it, unless "Disable cache" is checked in dev tools.
3. The request is sent as a fetch event to the service worker. There your custom code can query your custom cache and see if the resource has been stored there, and return it. If not you can forward the request to the network. (Not sure if "Disable cache" has any effect here).

Just hoped that someone could confirm that this is how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If with "internal cache" you mean the browser cache, then it is accessed *after* accessing the Service Worker cache (you need to swap your point 2 with 3). 
 If you set `disable cache`, this will affect only the browser cache, not the Service Worker one. The requests reaching this point, meaning no match found in the Service Worker cache, will go straight to the server side.

You can **think of the browser cache as a *fallback cache*** when implementing caching strategies with Service Workers.

Below you can find the cache order followed when an HTTP Request is executed.

 You can also read the [web.dev article](https://web.dev/service-worker-caching-and-http-caching/), explaining this in detail.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Francesco, excellent explanation. Yes "internal cache" = browser cache. But now I am confused, because if I use JS to insert an image on my page, the SW correctly gets a fetch event, then I remove the image from the page, then insert it again, and the SW does not get a second fetch event. (I do no page reload in this example). So something is holding that image in memory even when it is not used, aka a cache.

And when I check the "Disable cache" in Chrome dev tools, I get a fetch event every time. So in reality there is actually a cache before the SW.

Comment: If you see a fetch by every request when disabling the browser cache, I would guess that the sw does not find somehow the image in the cache, then falls back to the browser and to the server as the cache is disabled. AFAIK the only way to interact with the sw cache is programmatically (or wiping it out completely through the browser devTools). Which caching strategy did you implement for the sw?

Comment: No I see the opposite: I don't see a SW fetch event every request. This makes me think there is a cache *before* the SW fetch event.

Comment: 1. Open Google Chrome, go to https://www.athletium.app/go/ 2. Open devtools. Go to Application/Service Workers, click on Service-Worker.js. Put a breakpoint on line 71 (fetch event). 3. Click on the top right menu icon in the PWA. The breakpoint is hit. Disable break point and let it load the images. 4. Hide the PWA menu by clicking anywhere outside of it. 5. Set the same breakpoint again and open the menu. Now it doesn't get hit. 6. In dev tools go to Network and put a checkmark on "Disable cache". Repeat #4, #5 and the breakpoint gets hit.

Comment: Just want to point out that when the PWA menu is hidden, the HTML for all the images are removed from the HTML document.

Comment: Please see the answer I wrote to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

@Francesco linked to an article about service workers and HTTP requests (see graph in his answer). But it turns out that this graph is incomplete. Google Chrome's rendering engine Blink also has a cache that is checked first before a request is passed to the service worker. The devtools setting "Disable cache" disables Blink's cache. Explained here:

[What does Blink in-memory cache store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52950068/what-does-blink-in-memory-cache-store)

So in reality there are three caches, and they are passed in this order: 1. Blink's cache, 2. the service worker's cache (if implemented), and 3. the Browser cache. Add to that what ever cache is in the CDN.

Comment: Good point Björn! In the case of Chrome they refer to "Memory cache layer" just BEFORE the sw (as you guessed originally). Thanks for your question, helped me to dig a bit deeper into sw!!