# Script File is served from memory cache when using service worker on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, service-worker

I have done a PWA using service worker,I just importes script file in html file like below

If I update an changes either in HTML or Script file, that update is not reflected in service worker, always chrome serve the file from memory cache...but firfox serves updted file from service worker.

i want to know, why this happening ...any solution to resolve this

below one is html file

```
<html>

    <body>

        
        <div><h1>Staic,Hello All! </h1></div>

        <script src="2.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

below is script file (2.js)

```
const text = '<h1>Dynamic Hello All!</h1>'
const div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = text
document.body.appendChild(div)

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw2.js').then(function(registration) {
        
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
      }, function(err) {
     
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
      });
    });
}
```

below is service worker file

```
var cacheName = 'b7';
// var cacheAssets = [
//     '/1.html',
//     '/1.js',
  
// ]


self.addEventListener('install', e => {

    // e.waitUntil(
    //     caches.open(cacheName)
    //     .then(cache => {
    //         console.log(`Service Worker: Caching Files: ${cache}`);
    //         cache.addAll(cacheAssets)
    //             .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
    //     })
    // );
})

self.addEventListener('activate', e => {
    console.log('Service Worker: Activated');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames.map(
                    cache => {
                        if (cache !== cacheName) {
                            console.log('Service Worker: Clearing Old Cache');
                            return caches.delete(cache);
                        }
                    }
                )
            )
        })
    );
})

// self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
//     console.log('Service Worker: Fetching');
//     e.respondWith(
//         fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request))
        
//     );
// });

self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
    console.log('Service Worker: Fetching');
    e.respondWith(
        fetch(e.request)
        .then(res => {
         
            const resClone = res.clone();
           
            caches.open(cacheName)
                .then(cache => {
                  
                    cache.put(e.request, resClone);
                });
            return res;
        }).catch(
            err => caches.match(e.request)
            .then(res => res)
        )
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior in Chrome, but it's definitely browser-dependent and is somewhat surprising, since it violates the assumption that every request will trigger a `fetch` event once a service worker is in control of a client.

There is more context in this older question: [Chrome service worker not intercepting cached requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421110)

My advice is to [explicitly set `Cache-Control:` headers](https://web.dev/http-cache/) on your responses to ensure that there's always  a revalidation step required before a response can be used from the HTTP cache. If revalidation is explicitly required, the memory cache won't be used, and the revalidation request will trigger a `fetch` event in your service worker.